# unable to print Beanshell response in log file and cmd

Tags: cmd, jmeter

I am trying to print the below code in Beanshell PostProcessor

but i am getting

```
Code         :  log.info(ctx.getPreviousResult.getTime());
Error Message:  Cannot access field: getPreviousResult
```

Answer (score 1):

getPreviousResult is a method so syntax is:

> ctx.getPreviousResult().getTime()

So you code should be:

> log.info("{}", ctx.getPreviousResult().getTime());

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. now i am getting  "ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``if(ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponsecode()......."

Comment: I updated answer, can you show the full jmeter.log ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. [JMeterContext.getPreviousResult()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getPreviousResult--) is a function, not field, you need to add parentheses after it
2. You cannot print a [Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) value to *jmeter.log* directly, you need to cast it to [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) first
3. There is `prev` shorthand which stands for parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) so you can actually shorten your code

Assuming all above amend your code to:

```
log.info(prev.getTime().toString());
```

[image]

---

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) language mostly because [Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) so consider migrating to [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) on next available opportunity, you will not have to change the code.